# Are the steps in this Limit correct? $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n^{2k} + n^k} -n^k = \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to show that:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n^{2k} + n^k} -n^k = \frac{1}{2} : \left[ n\ge1, k>0 \right]$$

**Are these steps correct?**

Given $f(n,k) = \sqrt{n^{2k} + n^k} -n^k$ find the Limit as $n$ goes to infinity.

Multiply by the conjugate:

$$\left( \frac{\sqrt{n^{2k} + n^k} -n^k}{1} \right)\left( \frac{\sqrt{n^{2k} + n^k} + n^k}{\sqrt{n^{2k} + n^k} + n^k} \right) = \frac{n^{2k} + n^k - n^{2k}}{\sqrt{n^{2k} + n^k} + n^k} = \frac{n^k}{\sqrt{n^{2k} + n^k} + n^k}$$

Reciprocating:

$$\left [\frac{n^k}{\sqrt{n^{2k} + n^k} + n^k} \right]^{-1} = \frac{\sqrt{n^{2k} + n^k} + n^k}{n^k} = \frac{\sqrt{n^{2k} + n^k}}{n^k} + \frac{n^k}{n^k}$$

Rearranging and Combining "this & that":

$$\sqrt{\frac{n^{2k} + n^k}{n^{2k}}} + 1 = \sqrt{\frac{n^{2k}}{n^{2k}}+ \frac{n^k}{n^{2k}}}   + 1 = \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n^k}} + 1$$

Since $\frac{1}{n^k}$ goes to zero, we get:

$$\sqrt{1} + 1 = 2 $$

But since we Reciprocated to perform algebraic simplification, we have to Reciprocate back and we finally get:

$$\frac{1}{2}$$

Therefore:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n^{2k} + n^k} -n^k = \frac{1}{2}$$

**Similar steps can be used for:**

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n^{2k} - n^k} - n^k = -\frac{1}{2} : \left[ n\ge1, k>0 \right]$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument can be simplified and both cases can be simultaneously considered by observing that for any $k > 0$, $$n \to \infty \implies n^k \to \infty.$$  So $$\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n^{2k} \pm n^k} - n^k 
&= \lim_{m \to \infty} \sqrt{m^2 \pm m} - m \\
&= \lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{(m^2 \pm m) - m^2}{\sqrt{m^2 \pm m} + m} \\
&= \pm \lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{m}{m \left( \sqrt{1 \pm \frac{1}{m}} + 1 \right)} \\
&= \pm \lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 \pm m^{-1}} + 1} \\
&= \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 \pm 0} + 1} \\
&= \pm \frac{1}{2},
\end{align}$$
where the sign is preserved.

Comment: Thank you, both solutions are excellent!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do many of the steps. Since $n^k$ is positive,
$$\frac{n^k}{\sqrt{n^{2k}+n^k}+n^k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+n^{-k}}+1}$$
In the limit $n\to \infty$, $n^{-k}$ goes to $0$, so the limit is $1/2$.

Also note that you have an error in your calculation $$\frac{n^k}{n^{2k}}=\frac1{n^k}\ne \frac{n}{n^k}$$

Comment: Thanks for the catch on the typo. I'll change it. I did take the long way, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative by $x=\frac 1{n^k} \to 0$ and $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$ we have

$$\sqrt{n^{2k} + n^k} -n^k =n^k\left(\sqrt{1 + \frac1{n^k}} -1\right)=\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-1}x=f'(0)=\frac12$$

Answer (score 1):

As another alternative you may tackle it using inequalites:
Applying the Harmonic-Geometric-Arithmetic mean inequalities yields
$$\frac s{2+\dfrac s{n^k}}
 \:=\:\frac2{\dfrac1{n^k}+\dfrac1{n^k+s}}-n^k
 \:<\: \sqrt{n^k\big(n^k+s\big)}-n^k
 \:<\: \frac{n^k\:+\:n^k+s}2 -n^k
 \:=\: \frac s2\,,$$
where the parameter $s\in\mathbb R\backslash\{0\}$ was introduced to cover $s=1$ and $s=-1$ as in the question.
*Thus, one obtains an increasing lower and a constant upper limit squeezing the sequence terms.*

As $\,n^k\,$ and $\,n^k+s\,$ are never equal, the stronger "$<$" holds instead of "$\leqslant$" .

Comment: Very nice method!

Answer (score 0):

Since we're already discussing various methods of solving, perhaps another approach could be considered. By [Mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) we can write $$\sqrt{m^2+m}-m=\frac{m}{2\sqrt{\xi_m}},$$ for a certain sequence that satisfies $m^2\le \xi_m\le m^2+m$. Since, $m/(2\sqrt{\xi_m})\to 1/2$ as $m\to\infty$ (It's easy to verify)
we have the desired result.